# enabling "libc++_shared.so" to be enabled in the OpenCV android application

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, opencv, cmake

I wand to implement a project with OpenCV . I have imported the the  OpenCV SDK in the project and i am getting the error in as follows:-

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libc++_shared.so" not found
```

i have read your solution in stackoverflow. The link is as below:-

[Android Studio CMake - shared library missing libc++_shared.so? Can CMake bundle this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620739/android-studio-cmake-shared-library-missing-libc-shared-so-can-cmake-bundle/39628365#39628365)

and i have tried to implement a solution from github:-

https://github.com/jomof/ndk-stl/blob/master/ndk-stl-config.cmake

I could not find any solution.

I just want "libc++_shared.so" packaged into the apk and the SDK runs properly in my project. i have no knowledge about the build tool cmake or ndk-build.

Please give a simple solution so that i can enable "libc++_shared.so" in the application so that the OpenCV project run properly.

My Error Log looks as below.

[image]

My Project structure looks as:-

[image]

Earlier i have added CMakeLists.txt as mentioned in the OpenCV SDK as

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

 # dummy target to bring libc++_shared.so into packages
 add_library(opencv_jni_shared STATIC dummy.cpp)
```

and a dummmy.cpp file that may include  "libc++_shared.so" in the apk.
Yet No results.

Please help with a solution.

Comment: Hi, i am running into this as well, did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes i have found the solution.How can i help you?

Comment: I found it to actually. I found a GitHub project that had the files and copy them into mine and it started working the documentation says Android studio should have done this for me though.

Comment: is your project working now?

Comment: Not really..  everything I fix needs another dependency.  Now I'm looking for some lid blass open something .so files.  My main concern is why doesn't Gradle bring this stuff down.

Comment: where is the problem tell if i can help.

Comment: I just found am example by orielly using opencv 3 and it is working with some.major updates to the code base.  It doesn't work with the built-in camera taking pictures because the camera is using the original legacy camera or something and the picture quality is horrible but if I import pictures the camera on my phone takes it actually works.

Comment: hi have you got it.

Comment: I can get pretty rough panoramics, but I can never get it to do a full 360 around.  I'll take enough pictures to go beyond 360 but it just never stitches it completely together have you gotten around that issue?

Comment: working with 360?

Comment: I mean I want to panoramic that loops around and doesn't stop. I can turn a full 360° around and not see edges except from the bottom and top That's a separate issue.

Comment: tell me the camera that you are using.

Comment: Pixel 3a camera.

Answer (score 7):

Try to add the following line into your build.gradle file from the app section.

***arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"***

It must be added to the externalNativeBuild sub-section.

```
android {
    .
    .
    defaultConfig {
        .
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                .
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

btw: [Ranjit Vamadevan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8765956/ranjit-vamadevan), I don't see your solution here but you mentioned you found one in your comments directly. I can not answer there. Could you please share it with us too?

Answer (score 2):

This solved it for me:
Put the content of the C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\libs%platform%\libc++_shared.so file in your jniLibs folder(s).

Found here: https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx/issues/1122#issuecomment-296356682